# When passing functions to a method, why does using an anonymous function container work and not just the original function?

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

I'm new to JavaScript and was messing around with recursive timing events. The following just prints the next number on the countdown on a new line until `limit` is reached. A version on [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud5H4/).

```
function countdown(limit,initial,period){
    if (initial>=limit){
        document.getElementById('tag').innerHTML += '<br/>'+initial;
        window.setTimeout(function(){countdown(limit,--initial,period);},period);
    }
};
```

The above code does work, but the way I originally wrote it was with **this line:**

```
window.setTimeout(function(){countdown(limit,--initial,period);},period);
```

Kust like **this:**

```
window.setTimeout(countdown(limit,--initial,period),period);
```

Which **doesn't** work. Why must I wrap the function `countdown()` in `function(){}`? Is this the best way to do it? Why doesn't the way I tried originally work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way to do this.  `window.setTimeout` expects a function as its first argument.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){countdown(limit,--initial,period);},period);
```

is passing an anonymous function as the first parameter to setTimeout.

```
window.setTimeout(countdown(limit,--initial,period),period);
```

is passing the result of the executed function countdown as the first parameter to setTimeout.  In your case, the result of countdown is always `undefined`.

For further illustration, you could have also passed in a function to window.setTimeout like this:

```
var myFunc = function(){countdown(limit,--initial,period);};
window.setTimeout(myFunc, period);
```

Answer (score 1):

First argument of setTimeout should be a function. When you write

```
window.setTimeout(countdown(limit,--initial,period),period);
```

you firstly call your function. It returns undefined. This is similar to call

```
window.setTimeout(undefined,period);
```

So yes, wrap your countdown into `function(){}` it the best way.

Answer (score 1):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) accepts either function or code (to eval). Your `countdown` is a function, but

```
countdown(limit,--initial,period)
```

is function call result, which would be `undefined`, since it returns nothing. So, the second version could be simplified to

```
window.setTimeout(undefined, period)
```

which obviously wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

While all other answers are good and explain why your second approach to invoking `countdown(...)` function doesn't work, I want to add that you aren't restricted to wrapping the `countdown(...)` into anonymous function. You can also use `Function`'s [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method like so:

```
window.setTimeout(countdown.bind(null, limit,--initial,period),period);
```

Here the first parameter is the function's scope (as you don't reference `this` in `countdown(...)`, you can safely set it to the null). Check out the documentation on the link provided if you have any questions.